Locally stored PDFs open Document Viewer, but PDFs stored in Gdrive don't open Permission Denied message
I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.01 and as a consequence PDFs stored in Google-drive no longer open, I get:
Unable to open document “file:///run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=..."

Permission denied

If I download the file it opens in Document Viewer as it used to from Gdrive. Other file types in Gdrive open OK, it's just PDFs in Gdrive that don't open.
What can I do to fix this?
I followed the instructions in
Opening PDFs Denied Access Google Drive in Nautilus (Files)
but it did not work for me.
How can I open .pdf files from Google drive?
It used to work but a recent 'upgrade' fubar'd it.

This question is similar to: Opening PDFs Denied Access Google Drive in Nautilus (Files). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. I would tend to favour using this answer as the solution.

I followed the instructions as above, but it did not work for me.
How can  I open .pdf files from Google drive?
It used to work but a recent 'upgrade' fubar'd it.

I fixed this by logging into Google again.
As far as I could tell I was logged into Google, I see and access Drive through Files, getting Calendar reminders etc, but couldn't open PDFs in GDrive until I logged in again!

It appears to myself in my newbie ignorance that access is more or less routinely removed from GDrive files unless you are actually signed in. I.e. I can see files on my smartphone (logged in permanently) or I can see files in Firefox - if I log in. Once logged out then there are big problems, despite the GDrive mount entry remaining on Nautilus.
